# How to enable basic authorization in Spring Security?

Tags: java, angular, spring-security

I want to write an application with Spring Security and Angular where user after registration can log in.
I have already created functionality allowing user registration however I am facing an issue when it comes to login.
I am using basic authentication method which sends relevant credentials that reach the server and authentication is performed (security logs will be below) however even if authentication is successful there is HttpErrorResponse.
Code related to what I have is below.

Endpoint for login:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public Principal user(Principal user) {
    return user;
}
```

Request for login:

```
public authenticate(username: string, password: string, callback) {

const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
});

this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/users', { headers: headers }).subscribe(response => {
  if (response['name']) {
    this.authenticated = true;
    console.log(response);
  } else {
    this.authenticated = false;
    console.log(response);
  }
  return callback && callback();
});

}
```

Endpoint for registration:

```
@PostMapping("/users")
ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@RequestBody String json) {
    JSONObject user = new JSONObject(json);
    return responseGenrator.generateRegistrationResponse(userRegistrator.registerUser(user));
}
```

Request for registration:

```
public registerUser(username: string, email: string, password: string) {
this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/users',
  {
    "username": username,
    "email": email,
    "password": password
  }, { responseType: 'text', observe: 'response' })
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.responseStatus = response.status;
  }, error => {
    this.httpErrorResponse = error;
    this.responseStatus = this.httpErrorResponse.status;
  });
```

}

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) {
    try {
        httpSecurity.httpBasic();
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users", "/login", "/user").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .anonymous();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Security related filtering:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
    final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, HEAD");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.addIntHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", 10);
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Related security logs:

```
2019-04-10 16:14:54.721 DEBUG 16708 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/users'; against '/'
2019-04-10 16:14:54.721 DEBUG 16708 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /users; Attributes: [anonymous]
2019-04-10 16:14:54.721 DEBUG 16708 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9f9c73e6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2019-04-10 16:14:54.722 DEBUG 16708 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@2bc279a5, returned: 1
2019-04-10 16:14:54.722 DEBUG 16708 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2019-04-10 16:14:54.722 DEBUG 16708 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2019-04-10 16:14:54.722 DEBUG 16708 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2019-04-10 16:14:54.724 DEBUG 16708 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2019-04-10 16:14:54.724 DEBUG 16708 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@376adbc7
2019-04-10 16:14:54.724 DEBUG 16708 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2019-04-10 16:14:54.724 DEBUG 16708 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Related console log text:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/users' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: I think you missing a "Content-Type: application/json" header

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud I have added header to login request however unfortunately there is still HttpErrorResponse.